# What's wrong in the \tensor command?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

After a recent update of MikTeX (and TeX Live!) on my computers (right after my vacation :)) I am not able to compile my book. The book is big and complex, uses many `\if \else \fi` constructions in the preamble, uses my own custom macros and environments some of which ceased to work properly. Here is one of the troubles identified so far.

The following minimal text is not compiled by XeTeX both in MkTeX and TeX Live.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load fontspec and define a document font:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

% Load unicode-math and define a math font:
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}

  \providecommand{\tensor}[1]{\overleftrightarrow{{\mathbf{#1}}}}%

  \begin{equation}
  \tensor{\pi}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Compilation aborts with 0 pages of output after issuing the message:

```
! Internal error: fad native font flag in `map_char_to_glyph'
```

I am absolutely sure that 3 months ago the above example would be succesfully
compiled.

**What's wrong now? Should I change the above definition of the `\tensor` macro?**

Here is complete defintion of the `\tensor` macro in my own package.

```
%\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloraded{unicode-math}{%
  \providecommand{\tensor}[1]{\overleftrightarrow{{\mathbf{#1}}}}%
  \PackageInfo{handy}{\string\tensor\space has been declared using ^^J\space\space \string\overleftrightarrow\space from unicode-math package}%
}{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{accents}{%
    \providecommand{\tensor}[1]{\accentset{\leftrightarrow}{{\mathbf{#1}}}}%
    \PackageInfo{handy}{\string\tensor\space has been declared using ^^J\space\space \string\accentset\space from in accents package}%
  }{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{revsymb4-1}{%
      \PackageWarningNoLine{handy2}{\string\tensor\space has been taken from revsymb4-1 package.^^J You are recommended to load `accents' package before me}%
    }{
    \@ifpackageloaded{revsymb}{%
        \PackageWarningNoLine{handy2}{\string\tensor\space has been taken from revsymb package.^^J You are recommended to load `accents' package before me}%
      }{%
        \ifx\undefined\overset
        \else
          \providecommand{\tensor}[1]{\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\vec{#1}}}
          \PackageWarningNoLine{handy2}{\string\tensor\space has been declared using ^^J\space\space \string\overset\space from amsmath package.^^J You are recommended to load `accents' package before me}%
        \fi
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
%\makeatother
```

It uses 4 alternatives depending on what package is loaded. The most preferable alternative goes first and it assumes that `unicode-math` package is available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There have been some changes in `unicode-math`, for fixing some issues in multiletter identifiers using `\mathXY` commands.

Now, a single bold math symbol should be built with `\symbf` rather than `\mathbf`, which is reserved for multiletter things.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load fontspec and define a document font:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

% Load unicode-math and define a math font:
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\newcommand{\tensor}[1]{\overleftrightarrow{\symbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tensor{\pi}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For older document, you can reinstate the old meaning with a package option:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load fontspec and define a document font:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

% Load unicode-math and define a math font:
\usepackage[mathbf=sym]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\newcommand{\tensor}[1]{\overleftrightarrow{\mathbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tensor{\pi}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

but it's better to switch to the new commands as soon as possible.

Comment: So, if someone wants to redefine `\vec` macro should he or she write `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\symbf{#1}` in XeTeX but `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` in LaTeX?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I'm afraid so; maybe an alias for `\symbf=\mathbf` could be introduced. The fact is that `\mathbf{fi}` wouldn't have a ligature, with the old setup in `unicode-math`.

Comment: This is as crazy as the recent `atan2` argument switch in pgf.... Sigh. Back comparability should be (more) sacred. Well...

Comment: @Rmano That was exactly the problem: `\mathbf` was not backward compatible. And `\mathit` behaved in a very silly way.

Comment: @Rmano A choice had to be made, because `\mathbf` (and similar) was not backward compatible and rendered incorrectly multiletter identifiers. A good rule is *never* using `\mathbf` directly in a document, but hide it in a macro: `\newcommand{\vector}[1]{\mathbf{#1}`. If you had this, upgrading to the new `unicode-math` setup would just need changing *one* `\mathbf` into `\symbf`. But I'm often using `\mathbf` in the document myself `;-)`( in shorter ones).