# Unicode-math no bold math or greek letters

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

What could be causing this?

- I'm on Ubuntu 14.04
- I've uninstalled the Ubuntu TexLive packages and installed TexLive 2015 directly, and just updated today with tlmgr
- I've tried a few different `unicode-math` compatible fonts and the behavior is the same
- All of the Tex Gyre Termes and Termes Math fonts are installed
- They are installed at the system, not user level.
- I ran luaotfload-tool --update, resulted in no change

MWE below

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\begin{document}
Here is normal : $\rho$
This one should be bold : $\mathbf{\rho}$
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: MWE output]

Notice the missing second `\rho`.

The relevant log output is below :

```
Could not resolve font TeX Gyre Termes Math/B (it probably doesn't exist).
.................................................
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeXGyreTermesMath" -> "texgyretermes-math.otf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeXGyreTermesMath" -> "texgyretermes-math.otf"
luaotfload | aux : font no 26 (TeXGyreTermesMath-Regular) does not define featur
e smcp for script math with language dflt
luaotfload | aux : no font with id 26
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeXGyreTermesMath" -> "texgyretermes-math.otf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeXGyreTermesMath" -> "texgyretermes-math.otf"
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'TeXGyreTermesMath(0)' created for font 'TeX Gyre Termes Math'
. with options
. [Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic,BoldItalicFont={},ItalicFont={},Script=Math,Size
Features={{Size=10-},{Size=7-10,Font=TeX
. Gyre Termes Math,Style=MathScript},{Size=-7,Font=TeX Gyre Termes
. Math,Style=MathScriptScript}}].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. <10->"TeXGyreTermesMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;"<7-10
>"TeXGyreTermesMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+ssty=0;"<-7
>"TeXGyreTermesMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;+ssty=1;"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. 
.................................................
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeXGyreTermesMath" -> "texgyretermes-math.otf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU2' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU2/TeXGyreTermesMath(0)/m/n on input li
ne 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU2' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU2/TeXGyreTermesMath(0)/bx/n on input 
line 9.
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
luaotfload | load : Lookup/name: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" -> "texgyretermes-math.o
tf"
.................................................
```

This same entry is repeated for `Font family 'TeXGyreTermesMath(1)'`, `Font family 'TeXGyreTermesMath(2)'`, etc. a few times.

The answer to this question : [What's wrong in the \tensor command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263632/whats-wrong-in-the-tensor-command) works for me, but that question is very esoteric for the problem at hand, and this question is a better fit.

Comment: If I change `\mathbf` into `\symbf`, the bold rho appears.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks, I hadn't heard of the change from `\mathbf` to `\symbf`, what is funny is that I wasted literally over an hour troubleshooting before posting here, and the answer was given in seconds...I did extensive searching as well, the other answer isn't really listed when searching for things like "greek bold unicode-math." The answer in the duplicate question does answer this question, however, I couldn't find the tensor question when I searched for this problem...

Comment: Well, now it is, so this question is not bad at all. And I know about `\symbf` because I discussed about it (and the other changes) with Will on the bus going for our tour during the TUG meeting. `;-)`

Comment: As the comments indicate this is the `unicode-math` update issue, I've duped.